# Wallet has disapeared, by installing updates

Tags: wallets

I had several Ethereums in that wallet so I would like to get it back.
I only managed to get the Accounts back, but no Wallet.
But I still have the complete backup off the the whole Ethereum-directory.
So if anyone can tell me what the name is of the the file that holds the wallet-info?

Hans.

Comment: Hi Hans. Just add them back to the interface. All you need is the public key if the wallet. The wallets are not stored in the keystore but in the appdata directory as far as I know.